# How to set HTML Auto Indent format on Sublime Text 3?

Tags: html, indentation, sublimetext3

I have a question while I'm writing HTML code on Sublime Text 3. I just want to set auto indent format of HTML. For example, when I write p tag like under code, the indentation works like that.

```
<p>
Hello world!
</p>
```

But I want to write like under code instead of above.

```
<p>
  Hello world!
</p>
```

And not only p tag also ul, ol and etc.

How can I set auto indent format of HTML on Sublime Text 3?

Answer (score 78, accepted):

One option is to type [command] + [shift] + [p] (or the equivalent) and then type 'indentation'. The top result should be 'Indendtation: Reindent Lines'. Press [enter] and it will format the document.

Another option is to install the Emmet plugin (http://emmet.io/), which will provide not only better formatting, but also a myriad of other incredible features. To get the output you're looking for using Sublime Text 3 with the Emmet plugin requires just the following:

```
p [tab][enter] Hello world!
```

When you type p [tab] Emmet expands it to:

```
<p></p>
```

Pressing [enter] then further expands it to:

```
<p>

</p>
```

With the cursor indented and on the line between the tags.
Meaning that typing text results in:

```
<p>
    Hello, world!
</p>
```

Comment: Emmet is great, but it seems some people (including me) are having problems installing it on ST3...

Comment: Good to know. I'm not an expert and had no issues, but it's also the only package I installed so there's little opportunity for conflict.

Comment: Hmm, so I've just tried installing it on a different machine (same build of ST3) and it worked! Weird

Comment: Manual install will do the trick in case *Package Control* doesn't work. https://github.com/sergeche/emmet-sublime#how-to-install

Comment: Wow, this is awesome! No more alt+shift+w or copy/pasting 1000 times. Thanks and upvoted!

Answer (score 77):

## Create a Keybinding

To auto indent on Sublime text 3 with a key bind try going to

Preferences > Key Bindings - users

And adding this code between the square brackets

```
{"keys": ["alt+shift+f"], "command": "reindent", "args": {"single_line": false}}
```

it sets <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>alt</kbd> + <kbd>f</kbd> to be your full page auto indent.

Source [here](https://coderwall.com/p/7yxpdw/auto-indenting-on-sublime-text-3)

**Note:** if this doesn't work correctly then you should convert your indentation to tabs. Also comments in your code can push your code to the wrong indentation level and may have to be moved manually.

Comment: its best way to reindent linest

Answer (score 7):

This is an adaptation of the above answer, but should be more complete.

To be clear, this is to *re-introduce previous auto-indent features* when HTML files are open in Sublime Text. So when you finish a tag, it automatically indents for the next element.

**Windows Users**

Go to `C:\Program Files\Sublime Text 3\Packages` extract `HTML.sublime-package` as if it is a zip file to a directory.

Open `Miscellaneous.tmPreferences` and copy this contents into the file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple Computer//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>name</key>
    <string>Miscellaneous</string>
    <key>scope</key>
    <string>text.html</string>
    <key>settings</key>
    <dict>
        <key>decreaseIndentPattern</key>
            <string>(?x)
            ^\s*
            (&lt;/(?!html)
              [A-Za-z0-9]+\b[^&gt;]*&gt;
            |--&gt;
            |&lt;\?(php)?\s+(else(if)?|end(if|for(each)?|while))
            |\}
            )</string>
        <key>batchDecreaseIndentPattern</key>
            <string>(?x)
            ^\s*
            (&lt;/(?!html)
              [A-Za-z0-9]+\b[^&gt;]*&gt;
            |--&gt;
            |&lt;\?(php)?\s+(else(if)?|end(if|for(each)?|while))
            |\}
            )</string>
        <key>increaseIndentPattern</key>
            <string>(?x)
            ^\s*
            &lt;(?!\?|area|base|br|col|frame|hr|html|img|input|link|meta|param|[^&gt;]*/&gt;)
              ([A-Za-z0-9]+)(?=\s|&gt;)\b[^&gt;]*&gt;(?!.*&lt;/\1&gt;)
            |&lt;!--(?!.*--&gt;)
            |&lt;\?php.+?\b(if|else(?:if)?|for(?:each)?|while)\b.*:(?!.*end\1)
            |\{[^}"']*$
            </string>
        <key>batchIncreaseIndentPattern</key>
            <string>(?x)
            ^\s*
            &lt;(?!\?|area|base|br|col|frame|hr|html|img|input|link|meta|param|[^&gt;]*/&gt;)
              ([A-Za-z0-9]+)(?=\s|&gt;)\b[^&gt;]*&gt;(?!.*&lt;/\1&gt;)
            |&lt;!--(?!.*--&gt;)
            |&lt;\?php.+?\b(if|else(?:if)?|for(?:each)?|while)\b.*:(?!.*end\1)
            |\{[^}"']*$
            </string>
        <key>bracketIndentNextLinePattern</key>
         <string>&lt;!DOCTYPE(?!.*&gt;)</string>
    </dict>
</dict>
</plist>
```

Then re-zip the file as `HTML.sublime-package` and replace the existing `HTML.sublime-package` with the one you just created.

Close and open Sublime Text 3 and you're done!

Comment: Thank you so much! This fixed it for me. I'm on a Mac, so I did it by pressing [command + option + p], then typing PRV to select PackageResourceViewer: Open Resource, then going into HTML and finding Miscellaneous.tmPreferences to open the file. (I think PRV is a plugin, so others may need to install that first.) I edited, saved, restarted Sublime 3 and now indentation is working beautifully. Thanks again!

Comment: How do you zip the file as HTML.sublime-package in mac?

Answer (score 6):

This was bugging me too, since this was a standard feature in Sublime Text 2, but somehow automatic indentation no longer worked in Sublime Text 3 for HTML files.

My solution was to find the Miscellaneous.tmPreferences file from Sublime Text 2 (found under %AppData%/Roaming/Sublime Text 2/Packages/HTML) and copy those settings to the same file for ST3.

Now package handling has been made more difficult for ST3, but luckily you can just add the files to your %AppData%/Roaming/Sublime Text 3/Packages folder and they overwrite default settings in the install directory. Just save this file as "%AppData%/Roaming/Sublime Text 3/Packages/HTML/Miscellaneous.tmPreferences" and auto indent works again like it did in ST2.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple Computer//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>name</key>
    <string>Miscellaneous</string>
    <key>scope</key>
    <string>text.html</string>
    <key>settings</key>
    <dict>
        <key>decreaseIndentPattern</key>
            <string>(?x)
            ^\s*
            (&lt;/(?!html)
              [A-Za-z0-9]+\b[^&gt;]*&gt;
            |--&gt;
            |&lt;\?(php)?\s+(else(if)?|end(if|for(each)?|while))
            |\}
            )</string>
        <key>batchDecreaseIndentPattern</key>
            <string>(?x)
            ^\s*
            (&lt;/(?!html)
              [A-Za-z0-9]+\b[^&gt;]*&gt;
            |--&gt;
            |&lt;\?(php)?\s+(else(if)?|end(if|for(each)?|while))
            |\}
            )</string>
        <key>increaseIndentPattern</key>
            <string>(?x)
            ^\s*
            &lt;(?!\?|area|base|br|col|frame|hr|html|img|input|link|meta|param|[^&gt;]*/&gt;)
              ([A-Za-z0-9]+)(?=\s|&gt;)\b[^&gt;]*&gt;(?!.*&lt;/\1&gt;)
            |&lt;!--(?!.*--&gt;)
            |&lt;\?php.+?\b(if|else(?:if)?|for(?:each)?|while)\b.*:(?!.*end\1)
            |\{[^}"']*$
            </string>
        <key>batchIncreaseIndentPattern</key>
            <string>(?x)
            ^\s*
            &lt;(?!\?|area|base|br|col|frame|hr|html|img|input|link|meta|param|[^&gt;]*/&gt;)
              ([A-Za-z0-9]+)(?=\s|&gt;)\b[^&gt;]*&gt;(?!.*&lt;/\1&gt;)
            |&lt;!--(?!.*--&gt;)
            |&lt;\?php.+?\b(if|else(?:if)?|for(?:each)?|while)\b.*:(?!.*end\1)
            |\{[^}"']*$
            </string>
        <key>bracketIndentNextLinePattern</key>
         <string>&lt;!DOCTYPE(?!.*&gt;)</string>
    </dict>
</dict>
</plist>
```