# How modify reindent command source in SublimeText

Tags: sublimetext3

I would like to modify the source code of "reindent" command to enhance it for erb files:

To get:
[image]

Instead of:
[image]

I don't know how to get the file, Either browsing in "Preferences - Browse Packages" or with "PackageResourceViewer:Open Resource"

Thanks a lot

Comment: `reindent` isn't a command that is implemented in Python, it's an internal ST command. If you want to modify how `reindent` works, you should customize your [indentation rules](http://docs.sublimetext.info/en/latest/reference/metadata.html#indentation-options-children-of-settings)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to set HTML Auto Indent format on Sublime Text 3?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21190300/how-to-set-html-auto-indent-format-on-sublime-text-3)