# Autoindent on Sublime Text

Tags: sublimetext3, sublimetext, code-formatting

Are there any command/shortcut to auto-indent all my code on the page at once on Sublime Text 3?

e.g: On NetBeans I can do this with <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>.

Answer (score 84, accepted):

That's quite simple in Sublime. Just `Ctrl+Shift+P` (or `Command+Shift+P` on MacOS) to open the tools pallet, type `reindent`, and pick `Indentation: Reindent Lines`. It should reindent all the file you are in, just remember to save before running the command, or it may not appear.

Comment: Is there a faster way to do this?  As opposed to having to write 'reindent' every time?

Comment: You can always add custom shortcuts to these commands. Check it out here http://www.sublimetext.com/docs/key-bindings

Comment: it doesn't indent comments :(

Comment: For me in ST3, it indents whether or not I've saved the file, but it won't indent if I haven't selected the syntax.

Comment: but it does not work with files having 2 space indents...even after setting for 4 space indents...it does not indent all lines to 4 space indents. Maybe it is taking indents as spaces or I don't know but I still face this issue when I open files of github and it does not indent all lines which are not in 4 space indents..

Comment: I installed it on Linux (build 4143), and the shortcut comes by default with the key combination Alt+Shift+F (As suggested in other answers here). I confirmed this by going to the "Preferences" > "Key Bindings" menu, a screen showed the settings "{"keys": ["alt+shift+f"], "command": "reindent", "args": { "single_line": false}}"

Answer (score 74):

## Auto-indenting on Sublime Text 3 - "Key Bindings"

Just add this binding to your "Key Bindings - User" file:

***Preferences > Key Bindings - users***

```
{"keys": ["alt+shift+f"], "command": "reindent", "args": {"single_line": false}}
```

And adding this code between the square brackets.

Now you can use <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>f</kbd> as your auto-indent shortcut

You can also use the "reindent" feature through the command palette. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>P</kbd>

---

Ressources:

[Auto-indenting on Sublime Text 3](https://coderwall.com/p/7yxpdw/auto-indenting-on-sublime-text-3) by [Osvaldo Zonetti](https://coderwall.com/zonetti)

[Create a Keybinding](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32184077/4325011) by [Joe Lloyd](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2504407/joe-lloyd)

Comment: That's sweet.  I find that this works the best and is simple - at least for html.   It's the only one I've found that is really effective for HTML, but I was missing the single line argument, and I couldn't figure out why it was so erratic.  Thanks for that!

Comment: It is even work until now. This is the faster and best example for enhance the code interface configuration especially when you team up to build such a complicated project. I have not notice this exclusive feature from sublime. Very nice indeed!

Answer (score 3):

You can use one of many plugins which do the thing you need, for example, the one I am using:

- https://github.com/akalongman/sublimetext-codeformatter

Comment: Thanks for the tip!

Comment: It works great. Also fix the 2 space to 4 space indents issue...

Answer (score 2):

This should work as at sublime text version 3 :

```
{"keys": ["alt+shift+f"], "command": "reindent", "args": {"single_line": false}}
```

just copy and paste to your **preferences->keybindings->User** file.
Now select the entire code and press `alt shift f` to see the results.

For intending purpose you can use `Ctrl plus ]` and to unintend use `Ctrl plus [`

Comment: I'm on ST3 and this doesn't work. I had to add the key binding as described by chebaby.

Answer (score 0):

Select all and then choose Edit -> Indent Document ( Ctrl + Alt + I )

Answer (score 0):

For `C/C++/C#/Java` code, you can try [`SublimeAStyleFormatter`](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/SublimeAStyleFormatter)

For `PHP/JavaScript/JSON/HTML/CSS/Python/Go` Code, you can try [CodeFormatter](https://github.com/akalongman/sublimetext-codeformatter)

### Installation

Take `SublimeAStyleFormatter` as an example:

1. Bring up the Command Palette (`⌘+⇧+P` on OS X. `Ctrl+Shift+P` on Windows and Linux.).
2. Type “Install” and select “Package Control: Install Package”.
3. Select “SublimeAStyleFormatter” from list.

The “Packages” directory is located at:

- **Windows**: `%APPDATA%\Sublime Text 3\Packages`
- **Linux**: `~/.config/sublime-text-3/Packages/`
- **OS X**: `~/Library/Application Support/Sublime Text 3/Packages/`

### Usage

**Windows, Linux**:

- Ctrl+Alt+F: Format current file.
- Ctrl+K, Ctrl+F: Format current selection.

**OSX**:

- Ctrl+Alt+F: Format current file.
- ⌘+K, ⌘+F: Format current selection.

For example, on macOS, install the `SublimeAStyleFormatter` plug-in, and then press the `Ctrl+Alt+F` shortcut key, and then you can **Autoindent**.