# How can I auto indent in IDE with HTML that is all over the place? Sublime, Atom

Tags: sublimetext3, atom-editor, auto-indent

I am editing old HTML files that have indentation that is just bizarre and unorganized. There are divs within divs within divs x 1000. I couldn't go in there and try to manually move them around because structurally it is a mess. Is there a way to auto indent everything so it looks neat and organized?

I have access to Sublime Text 3 and Atom IDE.

Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to set HTML Auto Indent format on Sublime Text 3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21190300/how-to-set-html-auto-indent-format-on-sublime-text-3)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found this:

One option is to type [command] + [shift] + [p] (or the equivalent) and then type 'indentation'. The top result should be 'Indendtation: Reindent Lines'. Press [enter] and it will format the document.

Comment: Love it, had no idea

Answer (score 0):

In Sublime 3: Command + Shift + P (or CTRL + Shift + P) and then type "Indent" and choose "Indentation: Reindent Lines".

It will automatically format for you.